# Check condition and made calculation in MYSQL QUERY using INNERJOIN

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
SELECT 
    IF( trade_data.action =  'BUY' )  AVG( trade.data.price) AS  'BUYSUM',
    IF( trade_data.action =  'SELL' ) AVG( trade.data.price)  AS  'BUYSELL',
    AVG( trade_data.percent ) AS peravg, symbol.id as sy_id 
FROM trade_data
INNER JOIN symbol ON trade_data.symbol = symbol.id
GROUP BY symbol.id
```

I m trying to calculate rows prices `AVG()` and Wanna Check Some Condition in my query.
As you see in the Query .I need Same Condition in my query by using `Inner JOIN` or any thing.
`INNER` give me data but doesn't calculate any thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put IFs as arguments of AVG functions in this way:

```
SELECT
   AVG( IF( trade_data.action = 'BUY', trade.data.price, NULL )) AS 'BUYSUM',
   AVG( IF( trade_data.action = 'SELL', trade.data.price, NULL)) AS 'BUYSELL',
   AVG( trade_data.percent ) AS peravg, 
   symbol.id as sy_id
FROM trade_data
INNER JOIN symbol ON trade_data.symbol = symbol.id
GROUP BY symbol.id
```